# Zooming to layer extent in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, python-2.7, zoom

Regarding my plugin pyqgis 2.2, i can load a vector layer succesfully. But when i try to zoom to the layer extent it does not work.

How to do in order to zoom to the layer extent?

---

I have just tried your proposition.I  pasted your piece of code into my plugin. But unfortunatly, when i load a vector layer. I try to zoom to the layer extent (thanks to right click -> zoom to layer extent). I have no error message but there 's no change zoom to the extent of vector layer.

You can read the python.py (github plugin link)  here :

https://github.com/picardie-nature/clicnat-qgis/blob/master/plugin.py

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 17):

Something like below should work.

```
vLayer = iface.activeLayer()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
extent = vLayer.extent()
canvas.setExtent(extent)
canvas.refresh()
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it would be to select all features in the layer, zoom to selected and then deselect everything:

use this code:

```
vlayer.selectAll()
mCanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
mCanvas.zoomToSelected()
vlayer.removeSelection()
```

Comment: No don't do this. It will be bad for preformance.

Comment: I think this result is better as when I use OTF transformation, the top rated answer cannot zoom to the extent in transformed CRS.

Comment: This will decrease performance for large dataset.

Comment: If you need to zoom to an extent in a different CRS, best just transform the extent instead of using this working, but highly inefficient approach.